# can one calculate a p value in a distribution

Tags: r, probability, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have an event which happens so many times, [image]

I want to know how significantly is 1300$ in comparison to the distribution. which test should I use ?

Comment: What are you trying to find out? Are you sure you need to do a test? It might be helpful to add information about the data and where the number 1300 comes from

Comment: Are you trying to find out what's the probability that `Gross monthly salary` is greater than 1300? I.e. you're trying to estimate $P(Salary > 1300)$? Well, you have an estimate right there, in the form of the histogram. Follow @knrumsey's [advice below](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/393502/72690) to get the estimate of that probability (he calls it `p_val`).

Answer (score 2):

How about testing this empirically. Here is an example dataset for illustration.

[image]

Let $f$ denote the distribution of your previously observed samples and let $X$ be the new data point with $x=13$. If you want to test the one-sided hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
&H_0: X \text{ is generated by distribution } f \\
&H_1: X \text{ is too large to be generated by distribution } f
\end{align*}

A simple empirical p-value for this test is to count the number of observations which are larger than $x=13$ and divide by $n$.

```
p_val <- mean(data > x)
```

For this simulated dataset, the $p$-value is $0.028$ indicating upper extremeness. If you want to test the two-sided alternative hypothesis:
$$H_1: X \text{ is too extreme to be generated by distribution } f$$

Things are a little trickier due to asymmetry of the distribution. One possible option is to try to transform your data so that it is approximately Normal, and use a similar approach. Here's what we get for this data set.

```
library(MASS)
boxcox(lm(data~1))
transformed_data <- data^-1
standardized_data <- (transformed_data - mean(transformed_data))/sd(transformed_data)
hist(transformed_data, breaks=30, col='orange', main='Normalized Data')

test_statistic <- (1/x - mean(transformed_data))/sd(transformed_data)
abline(v=c(1,-1)*test_statistic, lwd=2, lty=2)
```

[image]

Obtaining a p-value for this two sided test now works like this:

```
mean(abs(transformed_data) > abs(test_statistic))
```

This yields a $p$-vaue of $0.048$.

Comment: can you also add one sided p-value for a certain number

Comment: i want to have the p value with 95% of confidential .  Do you think that it is possible ?

Comment: I want to be able to calculate the p with a confidence interval . why is it nor neccessary ? by the way I liked you answer already

Comment: P-values are usually reported on their own. If you want a confidence interval, try Bootstrapping. Re-sample the data, and compute the p-value. Repeat this many times and you get an approximate sampling distribution for $p$.

Comment: Okay, I am gonna accept your answer, could you please explain a bit your H0 and H1 hypothesis ?

Comment: You are interested in testing if a value of $x$ is "extreme" with respect to a distribution $f$. The null hypothesis claims that it is NOT extreme, and is generated by the same distribution. The alternative claims that the value is extreme compared to the other observations. If you know beforehand that you want to test that $x$ is larger than the others, then you utilize the first approach. If you don't know if it is larger or smaller, then you need a two-sided test.